# SimpleDataFormat is restrict to predefiend dates

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm doing this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mmaa");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
Date parsedDate = df.parse("Dec 19, 2011 2:37pm");
```

The result:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Dec 19, 2011 2:37pm"
```

As far as I know:

```
Dec 19, 2011 2:37pm

year -> yyyy -> 2011
month -> MMM -> Dec
day in month -> d -> 2
a -> AM/PM -> pm
minute -> mm -> 37
Hour (1-12, AM/PM) -> h -> 3
```

What's wrong in the formatting?

Comment: Your format has `MMMM`, not `MMM`. Also, you've specified `hh` which means "2 digit hour" when you mean `h` for "one or two digit hour". (Otherwise it would be 02:37) And you probably want `d` instead of `dd` as well...

Comment: Ok, is there any problem setting dd:mmaa and using e.g. 2:37pm? Because it works by this way...

Comment: Do you mean `hh:mmaa`? Well I'm somewhat surprised it works, but I'd change it anyway so that your code reflects your intention - you don't *actually* required two digits, so you shouldn't specify them. Just use `h` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify a locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mmaa", Locale.US);
```

Because the name of the month depends on it.

Comment: Ok... I was thinking about deleting the post.... I received negative for this question :-O I tried to search for the problem, but everything "was correct" by the formatting. But Locale is necessary.

Comment: @Orochi if your question is answered, you can not delete it.

Comment: This doesn't reflect the format requested, which has an abbreviated month name and a 1-or-2 digit hour; I suspect the OP should be using `"MMM d, yyyy h:mmaa"`. Specifying the locale is important as well, and this solution does *work*, but it doesn't actually fit the data.

Comment: @Jens: Yes, but that doesn't mean it's good to keep the incorrect format specification. The data has an abbreviated month name - so specify that. The data has a single digit for the hour - so specify that. I suspect the data would have a single digit for the day-of-month too - so specify that. Don't you think the format passed to the `SImpleDateConstructor` should reflect the expected data?

Answer (score 3):

`MMMM` - for full month ("December")

`MMM` - for short month ("Dec")

`h` - short hour of 12h format (2)

`hh` - 2-digit hour of 12h format (02)

And **always** use locale when you create `SimpleDateFormat` instance:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mmaa", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the problem... Locale

Comment: I suspect the OP really wants `d` rather than `dd` as well. But this is at least closer than the currently-accepted answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe question is worth comment, not answer... But I want 2000.